# SVG Mask is pixelated on retina displays

Tags: svg, retina-display, mask, screen-resolution

I have a simple cut-out rectangle with text in the middle.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <mask id="mytext">
            <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='white'/>
            <text>Welcome</text>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='blue' mask="url(#mytext)"/>
</svg>
```

However when viewing from a retina display the text edges become pixelated.
It does't happen if I only use text without masking it, but as soon the mask is used it breaks everything out.

EDIT: By Retina Display I mean, iOS and OSX both latest versions. All Browsers. I believe it might be a pixel density issue.

The interesting is while having

```
<text fill='url(#mypattern)'>Welcome</text>
```

The text is rendered sharply perfect. The problem lies only with masks being applied.

Here it is a jsfiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/s5kTK/embedded/result/) (please make sure to test on your retina display enabled device).

And here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5cPI.png) displaying the difference on iPhone (note that the edges of the text below and how pixelated it looks).

Comment: What are you using to render the text? Safari/WebKit? Chrome? Firefox? What OS, and what version?

Comment: Hi @Phrogz, I have just added further information to the question. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Demo looks fine on my 15" Retina MacBook running 10.8.4 and Safari 6.0.5

Comment: @Phrogz are you sure? you can even zoom in the page and pay attention to edges and see that the bellow is definitely not vector and gets pixelated. This also happens on iPhone and iPad. in fact I have just updated the question with a screenshot from iPhone where the difference is clear.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?  I have the same issue with iPad / iPhone.

Comment: hey @Brian, unfortunately I believe this is some kind of limitation which hasn't been implemented on browsers yet. It seems, masks are rendered as bitmap 72dpi and text fills uses vector. Perhaps a bug filling on webkit would help devs to give a special attention to it?

Comment: Good call - I agree that browsers should be doing this work.  Link to a bug report and I'll +1 it.